# How to change qwerty keyboard to standard mobile phone keypad?

Tags: keyboard, android

I just purchased a Lenovo p700i with Ice Cream OS on it. I can't seem to find where to change the qwerty keyboard layout to standard mobile phone keypad layout.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You can ask questions about android on http://android.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to get an alternative keyboard from the Google Play Store. [GO Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gokeyboard) and [Smart Keyboard PRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.cdeguet.smartkeyboardpro) look like possible alternatives, but there are [*dozens* (if not *hundreds*) of different keyboards](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=telephone+keypad&c=apps) you can get and install.